# Don't work Locale ID

Tags: delphi, localization

I develop my project in Delphi 2010 on Windows 7 (Russian localization).

When I started working on Windows 8 (English) and moved my project to Delphi XE3 I saw standard dialogs (like buttons, headers of MessageDlg and system errors) in English (must be in Russian).

Look at Project - Options - Version Info - Language, and saw Locale ID as "English (United States)" in "Debug Configuration - 32-bit Windows platform".

Look other configurations, and saw in three headlines like "All configurations - All platforms" (where all elements disabled)

Locale ID is "Russian (Russia)" and in all subtitles "32-bit Windows platform" Locale ID is "English (United States)".

OK, I changed in all configurations Locale ID to "Russian (Russia)". But It doesn't work - all messages in English. In properties of builded exe-file Language=Russian (Russia).
Tested it on Windows 7, Vista with Russian localization.

Comment: Switch your installed Windows 7 to English-locale and look if the OS-standard dialogs would be OS-standard English or non-standard Russian.

If you want a special application-specific messages, then use VCL message dialog functions + RTL translation to Russian.

By the way, did you tried `GetThreadLocale` when running ?

Answer (score 2):

The Locale ID in the version info has nothing to do with the language used for standard dialogs. You can even have multiple entries in version info for different locales.

The language used for standard dialogs depends on the language setting for the current Windows user. It is the same for all applications started under this user account and is independent of the language used inside the application itself.

Comment: @Arioch'The, that might be, but I didn't try. Normally I try to respect the user setting in such cases. After all, that's why it is a user setting in the first place.

Comment: +1 but I'd state it as "language used for standard dialogs depend on the current user interface language of the OS".

Comment: .. I mean it doesn't depend on any setting.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, in a Multi Language Windows installation the user interface language can be selected individually for each user. Of course, if only one language is installed only that can be used by the OS.

Comment: @Uwe ?? My Win7/64 language settings are 'Nederlands' (Dutch) and have been so from the beginning. My Delphi XE2 is English. The standard dialogs started from my Delphi program come with English buttons, however. Tested on my development machine and another Win7/64 machine that I deployed on. That seems to contradict your answer. OS confirmation questions *have* Dutch buttons. I would like my programs MessageDlg() buttons Dutch... Changing Program Options like the OP did not work.

Comment: @JanDoggen, the term "standard dialogs" should better read "Windows standard dialogs". Some dialogs are created by Delphi itself and such contain the language that is set for the library (see BDSSetLang.exe). Also some Windows dialogs allow the setting of some strings. In case Delphi uses this option also those dialogs contain the language set for the library. Besides English Delphi currently ships with German, French and Japanese translations of the library. For any other language you have to do the translations by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There's a consts.pas/consts.dcu unit in Delphi source, which contains all the translations of the standard dialogs. You can make a copy of this file and add it to your project. You can make your changes and build your project.
Make sure, that the original consts.pas/consts.dcu is not available (rename/move them).